# Can two checkboxes be linked in a way that only one will ever be checked?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on moving a form over to Excel. Due to the style of form I have to replicate the form with no changes.

On the form there are two check boxes, one for Full and one for partial.

I have the code spit out a warning box if both are selected. I think it would be easier to make it so that if one is checked the other will automatically uncheck.

```
' ERROR CHECK FULL/PARTIAL

If [F8] = True And [F9] = True Then

    MsgBox ("FAI can not be both a Full and Partial")
ELSE
'actual code in middle. 

END IF
```

Comment: Yes. They're called `radio buttons` instead, though, and they're round instead of square. Radio buttons are to indicate mutually exclusive options - only one can be selected at a time.

Comment: If you are able to change them to radio buttons you just need to give them the same Group Name and it will ensure only one is selected.

Comment: You can use radio buttons , or you can use checkbox ActiveX and on event Change code something to alter the value of another checkbox , or even you can put 2 checkbox with a cell who use a formula to swap the value if a checkbox is checked or not

Comment: @RonanVico: Windows uses checkboxes for when multiple selections can be made, and radio buttons when the choice is exclusive (this OR this OR this, but only one of them). Users expect radio buttons in this circumstance. Putting two checkboxes that they can check and then showing them an error when they check both is not only bad interface design, but it's confusing to the users.

Comment: If you must use a checkbox and this is a VBA form, then the checkbox1 code is: `CheckBox2.Value = Not CheckBox1.Value` and the checkbox2 code is: `CheckBox1.Value = Not CheckBox2.Value`

Comment: @Kenwhite: yeah i do understand that , but that wasnt his question , his question was can two checkboxes.... ? ... So i give him the right anwser , thx aniway ;)

Comment: @RonanVico: No, you didn't leave the *right answer*. The right answer is to use radio buttons. It's the way Windows was designed to work, and part of the purpose of this site is to share knowledge and educate people. Teaching the right way to do things is part of *sharing knowledge*. Besides, you didn't *answer*, you *commented*, and comments that also give bad advice are as bad as answers that give bad advice. The *right answer* is to use radio buttons, which work automatically with zero lines of added code to make sure the selection is valid and are the Windows standard control for that use.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do this. With Radio buttons, or checking if the other box is checked.

With radio buttons is simpler if one of them must be selected no matter what. You can enclose radio buttons on different frames to "group" them together as in the screenshot below. You can see that one on each frame is selected and you can only select one of the two on each frame.

[image: Excel VBA Form]

If you really want to use a Checkbox, you can use the code below.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1 = True Then
        If Me.CheckBox2 = True Then Me.CheckBox2 = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox2 = True Then
        If Me.CheckBox1 = True Then Me.CheckBox1 = False
    End If
End Sub
```

The first `If` checks if this is a click to Check the box, if it is, then it will check if the second box is already checked, if it is, it will un-check it.

This is assuming you are creating a UserForm, and these are not CheckBoxes on an Excel Sheet. The implementation would be the same, but the code will be slightly different.